# Facet filter for text field won't work properly in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I am using Alfresco Share 5.2 and currently working with search facets.
I created custom facet using Search Manager.

Facet is for property which is text value.
For some reason values from that property field are splitted by any special character like -, /, %, space, comma etc.

For example, I have value like this 444-555/789, and when facet filter is applied the value is shown splitted and one below the other.

(pictures attached below)

[image: Correct_Value_in_metadata_field]

[image: Facet_filter]

Has anyone had a similar problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue before. I think the issue is related to Solr or Alfresco Search Services.
My Alfresco Search Services is version 2.0.3, and it uses Solr 6.6.5.

For me, I set the property in content model in ACS(My version is 7.0) to be indexed and not tokenized.

```
<index enabled="true">
    ...
    <tokenised>false</tokenised>
    <facetable>true</facetable>
</index>
```

And then I did re-indexing for Solr.

Comment: I did those steps like you did and everything is working now as expected! @Aaron